# Fit variable number of views on screen in android

Tags: android

I have a variable number of ImageViews which I want to fit horizontally in a linear layout (with overlap). I tried different solutions but every solution either resize the images or makes the images overlap when they don't have too (I want the images to overlap only to make room for other images)

One approace i have considered is to adjust the margin dynamically, but I have no idea how to calculate it.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Did you consider using weight and weightSum?

Comment: I did, the images don't overlap, and they don't retain their size after a few are added

Comment: So you want zero scaling of images? How about positioning them absolutely by your own algorithm?

Comment: That's an option, but i couldn't figure out how to calculate the position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, if you will draw the images yourself at absolute positions within some view of size `totalSize` (width/height for horizontal/vertical), this class will calculate the first position (left/top for horizontal/vertical).

You have to give it the target area size + list of the image sizes in the desired orientation (it's written in generic way, so you can use it both horizontally or vertically).

For example for three images of size 100, 200, 100 (total 400) to be fit into area 310 big it will position first image at 0, second at 70 (overlapping 30 pixels of first image from right side), and third at 240 (overlapping 30 pixels of second image, and having 30 pixels outside of the view). So each image will have "cut" 30 pixels of its right side.

The "weighted" variant of calculation will "cut" from right proportionally to the image size, so returned positions in such case will be {0, 77, 232} hiding 23, 45 and 22 pixels of rights sides of those images.

(how to position the images on the calculated positions... probably `AbsoluteLayout` or `FrameLayout` will help to allocate the area, then put the `ImageView` (or what you use for images) into that, and position programmatically by the calculated positions).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ImagePositioning {

    /**
     * Return possible positions for various images from the list, to fit into {@code totalSize}.
     * <p>
     * When overlapping is needed, image 0 is at bottom, and last image is reaching beyond {@code
     * totalSize} (should be cut by view draw), each next image overlapping the previous one.
     * <p>
     * When there's enough space for every image even with spare room, images are centered into
     * available spare space.
     *
     * @param totalSize
     *         Total size of available space (width for horizontal or height for vertical)
     * @param imageSizes
     *         Widths (or heights) of images to position.
     * @return List with starting position for images.
     */
    public static List<Integer> calculatePositions(
            final int totalSize, final List<Integer> imageSizes) {
        if (null == imageSizes || imageSizes.isEmpty()) return Collections.emptyList();
        final int imagesN = imageSizes.size();
        int imagesTotalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < imagesN; ++i) imagesTotalSize += imageSizes.get(i);
        double freeSpace = totalSize - imagesTotalSize, posX = 0.0;
        freeSpace /= imagesN;        // free space per image (unweighted)
        if (0 < freeSpace) posX = 0.5 * freeSpace;
        final List<Integer> r = new ArrayList<>(imagesN);
        for (int i = 0; i < imagesN; ++i) {
            r.add((int)posX);
            posX += freeSpace + imageSizes.get(i);
        }
        return r;
    }

    /**
     * Return possible positions for various images from the list, to fit into {@code totalSize}.
     * <p>
     * When overlapping is needed, image 0 is at bottom, and last image is reaching beyond {@code
     * totalSize} (should be cut by view draw), each next image overlapping the previous one.
     * <p>
     * When there's enough space for every image even with spare room, images are centered into
     * available spare space.
     * <p>
     * This method is different from {@link #calculatePositions(int, List)} by weighing the
     * spare/cut space per image by its own size, so larger images will get cut more than smaller
     * images.
     *
     * @param totalSize
     *         Total size of available space (width for horizontal or height for vertical)
     * @param imageSizes
     *         Widths (or heights) of images to position.
     * @return List with starting position for images.
     */
    public static List<Integer> calculateWeightedPositions(
            final int totalSize, final List<Integer> imageSizes) {
        if (null == imageSizes || imageSizes.isEmpty()) return Collections.emptyList();
        final int imagesN = imageSizes.size();
        int imagesTotalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < imagesN; ++i) imagesTotalSize += imageSizes.get(i);
        double freeSpace = totalSize - imagesTotalSize, posX = 0.0, totalInv = 1.0 / imagesTotalSize;
        final List<Integer> r = new ArrayList<>(imagesN);
        for (int i = 0; i < imagesN; ++i) {
            final Integer imageSize = imageSizes.get(i);
            // calculate weighted free space for this particular image
            double freeSpaceWeighted = freeSpace * imageSize * totalInv;
            if (0 < freeSpaceWeighted) r.add((int)(posX + 0.5 * freeSpaceWeighted));
            else r.add((int)posX);
            posX += freeSpaceWeighted + imageSize;
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

JUnit4 Unit test used to develop this (TDD used to write this, but I didn't do final round of refactoring tests, so it's a bit unevenly split):

```
import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ImagePositioningTest {

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Fixed per-image positioning
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Test
    public void nullList() throws Exception {
        final List<Integer> r = ImagePositioning.calculatePositions(0, null);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertTrue(r.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyList() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> list = Collections.emptyList();
        final List<Integer> r = ImagePositioning.calculatePositions(0, list);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertTrue(r.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void singleImageFullWidth() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(500);
        final List<Integer> r = ImagePositioning.calculatePositions(500, list);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, r.get(0).intValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void singleImageSmallerWidth() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(500);
        final List<Integer> r = ImagePositioning.calculatePositions(1000, list);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(250, r.get(0).intValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleWidths() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> listTwo = Arrays.asList(200, 200), r;

        r = ImagePositioning.calculatePositions(300, listTwo);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(0, 150), r);

        r = ImagePositioning.calculatePositions(500, listTwo);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(25, 275), r);

        List<Integer> listThree = Arrays.asList(100, 200, 100);

        r = ImagePositioning.calculatePositions(310, listThree);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(0, 70, 240), r);

        r = ImagePositioning.calculatePositions(400, listThree);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(0, 100, 300), r);

        r = ImagePositioning.calculatePositions(490, listThree);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(15, 145, 375), r);
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Weighted positioning
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Test
    public void wNullList() throws Exception {
        final List<Integer> r = ImagePositioning.calculateWeightedPositions(0, null);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertTrue(r.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void wEmptyList() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> list = Collections.emptyList();
        final List<Integer> r = ImagePositioning.calculateWeightedPositions(0, list);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertTrue(r.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void wSingleImageFullWidth() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(500);
        final List<Integer> r = ImagePositioning.calculateWeightedPositions(500, list);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, r.get(0).intValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void wSingleImageSmallerWidth() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(500);
        final List<Integer> r = ImagePositioning.calculateWeightedPositions(1000, list);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(250, r.get(0).intValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void wSimpleWidths() throws Exception {
        List<Integer> listTwo = Arrays.asList(200, 200), r;

        r = ImagePositioning.calculateWeightedPositions(300, listTwo);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(0, 150), r);

        r = ImagePositioning.calculateWeightedPositions(500, listTwo);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(25, 275), r);

        List<Integer> listThree = Arrays.asList(100, 200, 100);

        r = ImagePositioning.calculateWeightedPositions(310, listThree);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, r.get(0), 2.0);
        Assert.assertEquals(310.0/400*100, r.get(1), 2.0);
        Assert.assertEquals(310.0/400*100 + 310.0/400*200, r.get(2), 2.0);

        r = ImagePositioning.calculateWeightedPositions(400, listThree);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(0, 100, 300), r);

        r = ImagePositioning.calculateWeightedPositions(490, listThree);
        Assert.assertNotNull(r);
        Assert.assertEquals(Arrays.asList(11, 145, 378), r);
    }
}
```